# Script asks for root password even it has executable permissions for everyone

Tags: permissions, root, chown

I have a script with name "somescript", which has executable permissions for everyone (755) but when I try to run it with a non-root user it keeps asking root password. I even tried setting to 4755 with no luck. Only admin user and user with root password run the script currently.

How can I make it so that, any user can run the script (but not change it)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     group1 2841 Jul  8  2014 somescript

user@node:~> somescript
root's password:
```

Edit: After tring Setuid and Setgid and seeing them not working I inspected more through script and found out script is checking for user name root, if not executing via sudo which forces to use root password. Commenting out this script should make it work via setting setuid as its owner is root.

```
if [ "$uid" != "root" ]
then
  exec sudo /someplace/somescript
else
```

Comment: Maybe it is soemthing **in** the script, that needs elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the script is asking for some operation with `root` privileges, which has nothing to do with permissions (in this case) as this operation will be performed by the current user and you don't have the `SETUID` or `SETGID` bits enabled.

You can, however, activate the `SETUID` bit on the script. This will make the script be run with the owner user, in your case `root`, but the user running the script doesn't need to perform any privileges elevation.

You can do this by running:

```
chmod u+s somescript
```

More on `SETUID/SETGID`: [Understand the setuid and setgid permissions to improve security](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/understand-the-setuid-and-setgid-permissions-to-improve-security/)

Comment: Thanks, found out problem was inside the script made with a root check, added solution on my question.